# Changing security policy properties at runtime

Tags: java, java-14

Here is my policy file

```
grant {
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "read,write";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "createClassLoader";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "setSecurityManager";
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "createSecurityManager";
};
```

Here is the test case:

```
System.setProperty("java.security.policy", SECURITY_POLICY_BASEDIR + "/create-classloader.policy");
System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
System.getSecurityManager().checkCreateClassLoader();

System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "default"); // change policy at runtime
System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
System.getSecurityManager().checkCreateClassLoader(); // expecting a "AccessControlException"
```

I am expecting a `AccessControlException` at the last line in snippet 2. Any pointers?

Comment: After the above code, try loading a class that is not part of the JDK. Then you should get the `AccessControlException`. At least that's what happened when I tried it.

Comment: Sorry to say this but that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The policy you put in place is queried when your java code tries to load a class since you are setting a class loader policy via method `checkCreateClassLoader()`. Just setting the policy does nothing. Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: yes indeed, it returns "access denied" but with `accessDeclaredMembers`. I want it to be `createClassLoader` error. The question is really simple imo, "Can we change it at runtime?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the security API was reworked between JDK 1.0 and JDK 1.1, direct instances of the `SecurityManager` class became a façade. The check methods delegate to [`AccessController.checkPermission(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html#checkPermission-java.security.Permission-) and constructing a new instance of `SecurityManager` has no effect at all, as these object do not encapsulate any state.

The [`AccessController` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/security/AccessController.html) in turn delegates to the current [`Policy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/security/Policy.html). Policies can change; there’s also a `refresh()` method to reload the current policy file. But accessing the `Policy` requires additional permissions.

So when you change your code to

```
System.setProperty("java.security.policy", SECURITY_POLICY_BASEDIR + "/create-classloader.policy");
System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
System.getSecurityManager().checkCreateClassLoader();

System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "default"); // change policy at runtime
Policy.getPolicy().refresh();
System.getSecurityManager().checkCreateClassLoader(); // expecting a "AccessControlException"
```

and add the line

```
    permission java.security.SecurityPermission "getPolicy";
```

to your initial policy file, you get your desired `java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "createClassLoader")` at the second invocation of `checkCreateClassLoader()`.